# Where can you obtain a scythe in Candy Box 2?

Tags: candy-box-2

How and where do I get a scythe in candy box 2?

I think I need it to defeat the teapot in desert fortress.

I currently have the summoning tribal spear, enchanted octopus king crown, knight's army and red gloves. I'm at the desert fortress level.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can buy it in the forge for 5 million candies once you visit the castle.

Comment: It's not in the store, it's in the forge.

Comment: -1 this answer is [still incorrect](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/137693).  I've corrected it, but my -1 stays, as I don't believe writing a random guess only to have it corrected by others deserves upvotes.

Answer (score 5):

You can buy it from the Forge in the Village for 5 million candies after visiting the Castle.