# I have 5,000,000 candies and the blacksmith still says that he has nothing more to sell

Tags: candy-box-2

Do I need to re-load my game, or what?

Comment: Related:  http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/137187

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where can you obtain a scythe in Candy Box 2?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/137187/where-can-you-obtain-a-scythe-in-candy-box-2)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The scythe will only become available after you have visited the castle. Once you've visited the castle, go to the smith in the village and you will then be able to purchase the scythe.

Comment: I've been in the castle and I still can't buy the scythe

Answer (score 2):

It takes a set amount of time before he has anything to sell. The last thing I got was the scythe, so I don't know if he has more after that

Comment: I haven't bought the scythe yet :/

Comment: How long, as an estimate?

Comment: @garfieldcfc gave you been into the castle yet?

Comment: @TZHX  No I haven't, why?

Answer (score 0):

You have to visit the dragon in the castle in order to unlock the scythe (5,000,000 candies at the Blacksmith).

Comment: Welcome to arqade! This question already has an accepted answer which answers the question in the same way as yours, so there is no need to answer again unless you have more details to share. In the future (when you have enough reputation to do so), feel free to upvote the answer you agree with.